# How to make horizontal cards using Angular Material

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I am trying to make these vertical cards into horizontal cards.

I am using the Cards component from Angular Material.

I can create cards only vertically, but I need the cards arranged on a horizontal level.

Here I'm attaching my code for reference.

HTML:

```html
<body>
    <div class="wrap">
        <!-- <img class="img-bg" background-image src="assets/logo.png"> -->
        <div class="text">
            <h1 style="font-weight: bold; text-align: center;">Welcome to Data Portal...</h1>
            <br>

            <mat-card class="example-card">
                <mat-card-header>
                  <mat-card-title>Catalog</mat-card-title>
                </mat-card-header>
                <mat-card-content>
                  <p>Here you can find the details about users/roles.</p>
                </mat-card-content>
                <mat-card-header>
                    <mat-card-title>Data Portal</mat-card-title>
                  </mat-card-header>
                  <mat-card-content>
                    <p>Here you can find the details about all the databases and tables.</p>
                </mat-card-content>
            </mat-card>
            <br>
            <mat-card class="example-card">
                <mat-card-header>
                  <mat-card-title>Data Portal</mat-card-title>
                </mat-card-header>
                <mat-card-content>
                  <p>Here you can find the details about all the databases and tables.</p>
                </mat-card-content>
            </mat-card>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```css
.example-card {
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
    max-width: 300px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRKzY.png)

Answer (score 2):

Create a container for all the `mat-cards`, then change the flow of the elements inside the container using CSS. For example:

```
<div style="display: flex;">
  <mat-card>...</mat-card>
  <mat-card>...</mat-card>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutGap="16px grid">
  <div fxFlex="25%" fxFlex.xs="100%" fxFlex.sm="33%">
    <mat-card class="mat-elevation-z4" >

    </mat-card>
</div>
```

See link below for reference https://zoaibkhan.com/blog/create-a-responsive-card-grid-in-angular-using-flex-layout-part-1/

Comment: Note that Flex Layout is [now in LTS mode, and it will no longer be supported at some point](https://medium.com/@caerus.karu/farewell-flex-layout-aaa567023769).

Answer (score 1):

You need a container for mat-cards first, then you can set flex to make it horizontal or even vertical if you want. Some code is below maybe will help you.

```css
.wrap{
display: flex;
margin: 0 auto //center the content
}

.example-card{
border: 1px solid black;
border-radius: 5px;
text-align: center;
height: 200px;
width: 400px;
max-width: 300px;
margin-left: 100px;
background-color: lightgrey;
color: black;
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <mat-card class="example-card">
    <mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-title>Catalog</mat-card-title>
    </mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-content>
      <p>Here you can find the details about users/roles.</p>
    </mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-title>Data Portal</mat-card-title>
    </mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-content>
      <p>Here you can find the details about all the databases and tables.</p>
    </mat-card-content>
  </mat-card>
  <br>
  <mat-card class="example-card">
    <mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-title>Data Portal</mat-card-title>
    </mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-content>
      <p>Here you can find the details about all the databases and tables.</p>
    </mat-card-content>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```